# Set Safari default behaviour to search if entry is not available?

Tags: mac, safari

Currently, my Mac Safari's default behaviour is quite different from Firefox or Chrome when an entry in address is not available as a URL. For example, if I type in "Mac HD", I get a message saying "Safari can’t find the server".

Firefox and Chrome would open Google search for this word. Not sure if there is any way to change this default behaviour? Through defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari does not automatically google the search but open a page like that and allow you to google it yourself easily.

[image: safari search]

Except when searching single word where it prepend and append `www` and `.com`.

Answer (score 0):

[Safari Keyword Search](http://safarikeywordsearch.aurlien.net/) allows you to use a custom default URL:

[image]